# How to Join 2 Tables in Tableau with separated fields

Tags: join, tableau-api, concatenation

I currently have a table that shows me all students that have had a test with their full name showing in 1 field. I have another table that shows me all the list of students in every class but the names of the students are split as first name and last name.

What I am trying to do is to join the two tables in Tableau with a Full Outer Join and then thought I could concat the field in the 2nd table but I am failing miserably and not sure how I can come around this issue.

If somebody could please advise on how I can link the tables so that I can then do some calculations like tests done = 7 (7 students) divide by 20 students in class but at the mo I am nowhere near that.

Answer (score 1):

Version 10.2, released today, allows a table join using calculated fields. If you have access to this version, create a calculated field right in the join dialog box. See the help/documentation at https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/help.htm#joining_tables.html#joinoncalcs for more information.

In case the link changes, here is what it says.

> The common fields between the two tables appear to be name. However,
>   in the Patron table the first and last names are in separate columns
>   and in the Contact table the first and last names are in the same
>   column. To join the tables on names, you can use a calculation in the
>   left side of the join condition to merge the first name and last name
>   columns together.
>   [image]
>
> The result is a calculated field on the left side of the join
>   condition that is accessible only from the join dialog. This
>   calculation converts the field in the Patron table into a format that
>   now matches the format of the field in the Contact table on the right
>   side of the join condition.
>   [image]

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get this version so will have to stick to my version 10.0.2. Any other ways to do this?

Comment: Too bad. This next idea may work, although I'm not 100% sure since you need an outer join. Create a calculated field that concatenates the first and last name fields in the format you want to join on. Then create a second calculated field. In it, compare the values of the name field from table 1 and the calculated field. This would be a boolean true/false field. Then filter on True. You'd need to do some tweaking to get the outer join effect. I don't have Tableau available at the moment but when I have a chance, I'll set it up and give you step-by-step instructions.

Comment: Thanks Sam M, I will give that a go